# What is the proper format for code for this datetime.strptime function?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a python program that ingests and processes data, yet one field is not converting properly. One piece of data comes in as a string of *java.time.OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)* and we use strptime to create a datetime object. Here is the simplified code:

```
$ python

from datetime import datetime

# source string format: (java.time.OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))
date_string = "2021-06-28T19:47:27.510670082Z"

# this works yet is not in the source format
date_string = "2021-06-28T19:47:27.510670"

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

print (datetime_object)
```

Results in this error

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 082Z
```

What is the proper format code to create the datetime object?

Comment: What is `082Z` in the time string? `Z` is an abbreviation for UTC, but what is `082` before it?

Comment: It seems like the last 4 chars are some metadata attached to the date string? `date_string[0:-4]` would be a quick way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [use `dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). You have time in ISO 8601 format with setting of timezone

```
    from dateutil import parser
    
    # source string format: (java.time.OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))
    date_string = "2021-06-28T19:47:27.510670082Z"
    
    datetime_object = parser.parse(date_string)
    print(datetime_object)  # 2021-06-28 19:47:27.510670+00:00
```

Comment: Thank you Andy! I did not know about dateutil, much easier!